# using 'fr' notation in css-template not working in firefox 82.0

Tags: css, reactjs, css-grid, css-modules, react-css-modules

I'm developing a website with a navigation bar and using autoprefixer for 'last 5 versions' compatibility.
For positioning the elements inside the header I user grid-template.

Something strange happens in firefox v.82.0
if I define the template columns' dimensions using only 'fr' measurements units, it breaks the layout. but if I change at least one of the column unit size to px or % it suddenly works

this is the code (cleaned, as I am using React and SCSS modules, and it is hurting the eye, too much clatter):

```css
.header-bar {
  display: grid;
  -ms-grid-rows: 1fr;
  -ms-grid-columns: 1fr 2fr auto;
  grid-template: "logo nav socials" 1fr / 1fr 2fr auto;
  background-color: rgba(#000, 1);
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  min-height: 4rem;
  max-height: 6rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.logo {
  grid-area: logo;
  justify-content: center;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 10px;
  img {
    min-width: 100px;
  }
}

.nav-bar {
  grid-area: nav;
}

.social-links-group {
  grid-area: socials;
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.social-link {
  margin: 0 1vw;
  width: 3%;
  padding: 2px;
  min-width: 25px;
  svg {
    fill: rgba($primaryFontColor, 1);
  }
  svg:hover {
    fill: rgba($secondaryColor, 1);
  }
}
```

```html
<header class="header-bar">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src=".../" />
  </div>
  <nav class="desktop-nav-bar">
    <ul>
      <li><a aria-current="page" class="link active" href="">Link1</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="">Link2</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="">Link3</a></li>
      <li><a href="" class="link">Link4</a></li>
      <li><a class="link" href="">Link5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="social-links-group">
    <a href="" class="social-link">
      ...
    </a>
    <a href="" class="social-link">
      ...
    </a>
    <a href="" class="social-link">
      ...
    </a>
  </div>
</header>
```

On firefox v.82.0, it looks like that:
[image: wrong layout]

Where it should look like that:
[image: correct layout]

NOW, some of you might notice that I apply styling on class selector 'nav-bar' that doesn't exist in the HTML.
However, as mentioned above, the problem can be solved even without addressing this specific issue, if I only replace one of the column unit sizes to px or %.

Can someone suggest a reasonable explanation as to why this is happening?

Comment: Hi sorry, updated. in the .header-bar

Comment: Unable to replicate in FF85 or Chrome

Comment: @Paulie_D - thanks. can you suggest what can I provide that will make it possible to replicate?
I don't mind posting all files here... but that felt too much of a mess... would that be better? is there another option?

Comment: you just need to edit the snippet with enough code to demonstrate the problem. At the moment it's not doing that.

Comment: @Paulie_D - what is missing? the code originally is written in react, I gave the rendered HTML in full (without base64 img src, or unneeded svg components) . I'll update the css to contain all of the code... what else do you want me to put here?

Comment: @Paulie_D - added the rest of the css

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if use of unit `fr` is a good idea at all at the moment.

It seems the unit is not supported by browsers well and `canIuse.com` marks it as experimental at all...

I am not sure if I got the right information ...

But maybe you want to check it out yourself:
https://caniuse.com/?search=CSS%20API%3A%20fr

Comment: Hi, thanks, man. I am not that fluent with caniuse queries so I didn't know how to verify by myself. that's interesting, I'd add that I don't see it complaining in the inspector windows. but I'll take that in count, thanks!